# PHPWord Template looping through query results not populating Values

Tags: php, mysql, phpword

I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not close zip file.' in /home/dyken/public_html/PHPWord/Template.php:109 Stack trace: #0 /home/dyken/public_html/lettersWord.php(40): PHPWord_Template->save('MemberLetters.d...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/dyken/public_html/PHPWord/Template.php on line 109
```

I have this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT distinct p.person_id, fname_mi, lname, company_name,
addr1, addr2, city, st, zip, greeting, email, fullName
FROM person p
INNER JOIN person_category c
on c.person_id = p.person_id
WHERE category_id = 1
order by lname, fname_mi, company_name";

$result = mysqli_query($dlink,$sql);

require_once 'PHPWord.php';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('letters/testLetter.docx');

$document->setValue('Value1', $row[1]);
$document->setValue('Value2', $row[2]);
$document->setValue('Value3', $row[3]);
$document->setValue('Value4', $row[4]);
$document->setValue('Value5', $row[5]);
$document->setValue('Value6', $row[6]);
$document->setValue('Value7', $row[7]);
$document->setValue('Value8', $row[8]);
$document->setValue('Value9', $row[9]);
$document->setValue('Value10', $row[10]);
$document->setValue('Value11', $row[11]);
$file = 'MemberLetters.docx' . $row[0];
$document->save($file);

if(!$file) {
    // File doesn't exist, output error
    die('file not found');
}
else {
     header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    readfile($file);
 }

 unlink($file);

 exit;
  }
```

`testLetter.docx` contains this:

```
${Value1} ${Value2}
${Value3}
${Value4}
${Value5}
${Value6}, ${Value7}  ${Value8}
```

I cannot get the query to populate the Values in the letter.

The query produces results elsewhere in the website, so I know that works.

`$dlink` is my `$host, $user, $password` and `$dbname` connection

I am getting documents in the letters folder, but not as many as I expect and they are all exact copies of `testLetter.docx` with the `${Value1}`, etc. and not the data from my query.

I have tried different variations of the code, but I can never get any of my query results in place of the `$Values`. Can someone please help me with this?  I'm new to PHPWord.

Answer (score 0):

I have also struggle with this for a while and it seems to be the same kind of problem. Apparently word generates different kinds of xml depending on how you create your document, for example, if you made a mistake when writing ${Value1} and get back to correct it, the xml generated is different from the one if you write it correctly from the beginning.

Searching in Internet I found this code in https://phpword.codeplex.com/workitem/49 that worked for me and maybe could work for you. It is to replace how the setValue method works.

Also you can find more information of what I'm talking about at http://phpword.codeplex.com/discussions/268012